# Tabulator: Load editor params on cell focus

Tags: vue.js, tabulator

When we focus on a row, this row loads all editor params of all editable columns, is there a way to only load the editor params only when we focus on that editable column?

Comment: Hi, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No. What do you want to achieve? Example code would be helpful.

Comment: I have a lot of editable columns with dynamic arrays, and i pass this arrays to autocomplete with editor params, and when i move between rows(on a cell without editor params), every editor params are loaded, making tabulator less responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass a callback function into the ***editorParams*** column definition option that will be called when the editor is loaded. this function will need to return the params object:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorParams:function(cell){
    return {values:["bob", "steve", "jim"]};
}
```

full details can be found in the [Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#edit-builtin)